# Flutter Video recording is returning exception when I am stoping the video recording

Tags: ios, flutter, camera, video-recording, flutter-ios

I am working on flutter camera, Video recording through camera is working perfectly on android devices, but on IOS devices it is returning me Error: "Error Message: Video is not recording!". Code of starting video recording, and stopping is:

```
    cameraSwitch = false;
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return null;
    }

    if (controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      return null;
    }

    try {
      try {
        await controller.startVideoRecording();
      } catch (Exception) {
        print("starting issue");
      }
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e, "start");
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _stopVideoRecording() async {
    if (!controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      return null;
    }

    try {
      final video = await controller.stopVideoRecording();
      controller.dispose();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e, "stop");
      return null;
    }
  }
```

When I started video Recording, it is not returning any kind of exception but when I stop VideoRecording, it said that no video recording is in progress, means that camera is not recording any video.

Comment: did you add permission in the info.plist?

Comment: Yes, I gave all the required permissions in the info.plist.

Comment: update the question with the exception.